# Date changes results if called with an array of parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried the following script with both Node.js and my Chrome console:

```
console.log(new Date([1988,11,5]))
console.log(new Date(1988,11,5))
```

I was expecting the two methods to give the same results, but they behave differently:

```
Sat Nov 05 1988 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
Mon Dec 05 1988 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

In particular, the second field, which specifies the month, starts the counting from zero in the first case.

I would expect the month starting from zero in both cases, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The first one is a non-standard call to the `Date` constructor, and JavaScript implementations are free to interpret non-standard parameters in whatever way they choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second call, `new Date(1988, 11, 5)`, matches the [specific format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) required by the specification for the `Date` constructor:

> new Date (year, month [, date [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, ms ] ] ] ] ] )

The first call will be passed through to the [other form of the constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), as you're passing in a single array:

> new Date (value)

Looking at the steps here, it will be calling an internal implementation detail, `ToPrimitive`, on the array.  Following the specification through the definitions of [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) and [`[[Default Value]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8), we see that the `value` argument passed to `new Date` in your first instance is a string representation of the array, ie `1988,11,5`.

Going back to the [spec for `new Date (value)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), we see that if the type is a String, which it now is, it will be handed off to the same code that is used for [`Date.Parse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2), which says:

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15). **If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.** Unrecognisable Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN.

(emphasis mine).

So, the implementors of V8, Chrome's and Node.js' JavaScript engine, have chosen to recognise and parse that string using a 1-based month.  But because it's not in the spec, it might change, and it might be different in different implementations/browsers, so don't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I decided to not use the array one althought I was pretty tempted :p

Answer (score 2):

The first line is not a valid Date constructor; it doesn't accept an array element as parameter. I think it's assuming it as a string value and is intepreted as `yyyy,mm (1 based),dd`.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

These are equivalently a wrong init:

```
console.log(new Date([1988,11,5]))
console.log(new Date([1988,11,5].toString()))
console.log(new Date("1988,11,5"))
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Lweww6et/